# Express.js Unauthorized error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have method

```
router.post('/user',passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function (request, res) {
  res.send(request.user);
});
```

and authorization token

```
"JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyIkX18iOnsic3RyaWN0TW9kZSI6dHJ1ZSwic2VsZWN0ZWQi"
```

when i send request to this route from postman everything is working.

but when i send request from angular application with same token its throw with error unauthorized

```
    getUser() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return this.http.post('localhost:8000/api/user/', {
      headers
    })
      .map((data: Response) => data.json())
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

Comment: Check the headers once.

Comment: can you share the angular code snippet without it no one will be able to help.

Comment: @Shubham i check headers token is the same

Comment: are you using ionic ? or is this local storage the browser's local storage ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending headers like an header object, use `RequestOptions` to wrap it and then send it via your post request.

your code will be like:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
getUser() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('token'));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('https://dropali.com/api/user/',options)
        .map((data: Response) => data.json())
        .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

Also a suggestion instead of getting your `token` while your post request retrieve it first in a variable and check if it's there or not, If not then do whatever is necessary if it is successfully retrieved then `make post request`.

Comment: I wrap headers to RequestOptions but same result

Comment: is it that the localstorage your are refereeing here is from the ionic app's localstorage i.e. this code snippet is of ionic app ?

Comment: this is browsers's localstorage

Comment: have you tried printing the header token to check your are getting one in your post request

Comment: you can do it be `console.log(req.get("Authorization"));`

Comment: with get method it is work, but post method gives unautorized

Comment: No I meant are you able to print the `jwt token` in your login post request above is how you will print the token if you are getting any .

Answer (score 0):

1.) Check at the server side you are getting the token or not.
2.) if you are not getting the token then check **Developer option** > Network > your request's header tag and see whether the token is going or not
3.) if not going the problem is in a front and else it can because of cross origin..

### FRONT END CODE EXAMPLE

```
 var token = localStorage.Authorization     
 var options = {
     url: '/user',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': token
     }
 }
 $http(options)
    .then((data) => console.log(data.data))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

if front end is ok then you should check CROSS

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
    next();
})
```

OR

```
npm install cors --save
app.use(cors());
```